# Javascript RegEx and escaping advice needed

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to replace one or more question marks with a replacement (template language), like that:

```
var translation = "this is a ???";
console.log(translation.replace(/(\?+)/g, "replacement")); //this is a replacement
```

But now, I recently ran into an issue where the question mark was actually intended as a question and should not be escaped. I decided to go for the `~` as escaping character, so this should not be escaped:

```
var translation = "this should not be escaped, cause it's a question, is it~?";
console.log(translation.replace(/[^~](\?+)/g, "replacement"));
```

Works so far. However, if I go with multiple question marks (requirement for the template syntax), I end up with crap:

```
var translation = "this should not be escaped, cause it's a question, is it~???";
console.log(translation.replace(/[^~](\?+)/g, "replacement")); 
//this should not be escaped, cause it's a question, is it~replacement  <-- ???
```

Any suggestion on how to do that? A classical `\` as escaping character would make me happier than the `~` but I ran into issues with that as well.

Comment: An escape character generally only escapes one character -- it would be unusual to have `~` escape a *series* of `?`.  Instead it would make sense to write `~?~?~?`

Comment: @ExplosionPills that's actually a good point.

Comment: for people who needs a jsfiddle link to work on this  

http://jsfiddle.net/A4SGh/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/A4SGh/1/ 
barmar's solutions works !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~` should probably be used to escape only a single character (which I think would be expected).  Users of the template could write `~?~?~?` to escape multiple characters.

As for the replacement, `[^~]` still selects a character.

```
translation.replace(/([^~])\?+/g", "$1replacement")
```

The `$1` will insert the selected character back again

Answer (score 1):

Use [*negative lookbehind*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
translation.replace(/(<!~)\?+/g, "replacement");
```